# Create absolute Uri in c#

Tags: c#, uri

My code does not work, why?

```
Uri urlNext = new Uri("product/100.aspx",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
urlNext = new Uri(new Uri("http://www.camb.com/used"), urlNext);
string url = urlNext.AbsoluteUri;
```

I want to get: `"http://www.camb.com/used/product/100.aspx"`
Instead I get: `"http://www.camb.com/product/100.aspx"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need / at end of uri:

```
Uri urlNext = new Uri("product/100.aspx",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
urlNext = new Uri(new Uri("http://www.camb.com/used/"), urlNext);
string url = urlNext.AbsoluteUri;
```